# Can't convert php page to PDF

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

I am trying to print php report that use records from mysql database & formated with CSS and which have layout as below,

[image]

I want ti convert this page with PDF like [click Here](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_001.pdf)

I've already use tcpdf but it returns error because of records from mysql.Have you any Idea?

Comment: what is that `error`  ?

Comment: Its Notice: Undefined offset: 47 in `E:\xampp\htdocs\test\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 17199`

Comment: I uses `file_get_contents` to load page

Comment: You need to make use of `include` , not `file_get_contents`

Comment: It returns page but without PDF format.Here is my code $html = `include('module/report/balance_sheet.php');
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [DOMpdf](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), for me it's the best, and the easier to deal. He converts pure html, into PDF files.